# How to delete specific columns from all excel workbooks in a particular folder

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a folder in which I have about 30 excel files. In each of these files, I need to delete about 20 specific columns.

Here are some details:

1. I am using Excel 2013
2. The columns are in the first sheet of the excel file. each file can have several sheets, but the columns that need to be deleted are in the first sheet.
3. Here are the names of the columns but please note, the columns are sometimes repeated:

   Heather

   National Light

   General

   Louisa

   Terruin

Would love some help.

Comment: I'm lost - are you saying you want to delete all columns title Heather, Nation Light, General, Louisa and Terriun?

Comment: I want to delete all the columns titled Heather, Nation Light, General, Louisa and Terriun, from all the workbooks in the folder.

Comment: Its a big manual work. I go to each file, manually select the columns and delete them.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you actually only want a worksheet function, but since you've not researched yourself I'm guessing you don't know what options you have and therefore VBa will suffice.

This VBa does it for you but it does mean pasting it into each worksheet, but since you only have 30, I'll assume this is manageable.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim columnTitles(0 To 5) As String
    columnTitles(0) = "Heather"
    columnTitles(1) = "National Light"
    columnTitles(2) = "General"
    columnTitles(3) = "Louisa"
    columnTitles(4) = "Terruin"

Do While (True)
Dim didDelete As Boolean
didDelete = False

     Dim c As Range
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange

             If c.Row > 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If

            For Each Title In columnTitles

                If (Title = c.Value) Then
                    Columns(c.Column).Delete
                    didDelete = True
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next
        Next c

        If (didDelete = False) Then
        Exit Do
        End If


Loop

End Sub
```

Before
[image]

After

[image]

(I know I left out National Light in the screen shot, but I have tested it and it works)

Comment: Related: [Deleting columns from Excel](http://superuser.com/q/898854/87805)